# Improving speed of method after adding value from different table aspn.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, entity-framework

I've got two tables: `Index` and `Codes`

when one condition is true, I need to check whether the `Index` is still valid and for that I need to get `EndDate` of the code which is in `Codes` table (as I've got only id of code in `Index` table)
This is how I do that:

1) First I get all Codes that have ended already (approx 3k+ items)

```
            var goods = _context.Codes.Select(a =>
              new Codes
              {
                  Loid = a.Loid,
                  Pid = a.Pid,
                  Code = a.Code,
                  Startdate = a.Startdate,
                  Enddate = a.Enddate
              })
              .Where(x => x.Enddate < DateTime.Now)
               .ToList();
```

then I'm taking my Index and adding values there as well as `CodeEnd` from `Codes` list above:

```
query = _context.VpAbcIndex
             .AsNoTracking()
            .Select(e => new VpAbcIndex
            {
                Id = e.Id,
                ParentName = e.ParentName ?? "!",
                ParentEndDate = e.ParentEndDate,
                ParentStartDate = e.ParentStartDate,
                ParentCode = e.ParentCode,
                ParentNote = e.ParentNote ?? "",
                ParentStatus = e.ParentStatus,

                ChildName = e.ChildName ?? "!",
                ChildId = e.ChildId,
                ChildEndDate = e.ChildEndDate,
                ChildStartDate = e.ChildStartDate,

                CodeEnd = (filter.Level == 0) ? goods
               .FirstOrDefault( x => x.Code == e.ParentCode).Enddate :
               (filter.Level == 1) ? goods
               .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == e.ChildCode).Enddate :
               (filter.Level == 2) ?
               goods
               .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == e.GrandChildCode).Enddate : null
            })
            ;
        }
```

That's approx 10k items. It doesn't seem that much however it takes quite a long time for them to appear in my browser. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a faster way to join these values?

Comment: you could improve a little by add no tracking to the codes query

Comment: Didn't help much tough

Comment: Select only the field that you need from Code: Code, Enddate. Minor improvement if any, when people are selecting the whole object, it helps by reducing the amount of data. Here I expect no gain from this. Especially on 3k elements But do you have any benchmark? Some Stopwatch to see what's going on.

Comment: 1. Instead of selecting all the thousands of rows, implement pagination and select only a page of rows. 2. if `goods` is another table, then try to use JOIN instead of using `FirstOrDefault`. 3. Avoid using `filter.Level == 1` etc inside the query... think of have this out of the query and create a criteria beforehand and use the criteria in the query.